# Merge/Combine multi-dimensions from a list to a new array with Python

Tags: python, arrays

I would like to merge/combine each item in a list, which has multi-dimensions, into a new array. Below is my code and expectation.

Example of 2D dimensions:

Input: `[[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6]], [[7, 8], [9, 10], [11, 12]]`

Output: `[[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6], [7, 8], [9, 10], [11, 12]]`

However, the dimensions are **dynamic**, they can be `[1, 2, ...]`

```
import numpy as np

regular_list = []
regular_list.append([[[-0.1905   , -0.4675   ],[-0.573    , -0.8115   ]], [[-0.468    , -0.3585   ],[-0.8145   , -0.7735   ]], [[-0.356    , -0.1435   ],[-0.7645   , -0.5415   ]]])
regular_list.append([[[-0.145     , 0.52      ],[-0.065     , 0.195     ]], [[-0.535     , 0.405     ],[-0.05      , 0.285     ]], [[-0.39      , 0.375     ],[-0.275     , 0.26      ]]])
regular_list.append([[[-0.2445    , 0.1275    ],[-0.229    , -0.147    ]], [[-0.117    , -0.043    ],[-0.151    , -0.046    ]], [[0.03      , 0.0245    ],[0.047    , 0.049    ]]])
  
flat_list = [i for i in regular_list]

print('Original list', regular_list)
print('Transformed list', flat_list)
```

Current:

```
[[[[-0.1905, -0.4675], [-0.573, -0.8115]], [[-0.468, -0.3585], [-0.8145, -0.7735]], [[-0.356, -0.1435], [-0.7645, -0.5415]]],
 [[[-0.145, 0.52], [-0.065, 0.195]], [[-0.535, 0.405], [-0.05, 0.285]], [[-0.39, 0.375], [-0.275, 0.26]]],
 [[[-0.2445, 0.1275], [-0.229, -0.147]], [[-0.117, -0.043], [-0.151, -0.046]], [[0.03, 0.0245], [0.047, 0.049]]]]
```

**Expectation:**

```
[[[[-0.1905, -0.4675], [-0.573, -0.8115]], [[-0.468, -0.3585], [-0.8145, -0.7735]], [[-0.356, -0.1435], [-0.7645, -0.5415]]],
 [[-0.145, 0.52], [-0.065, 0.195]], [[-0.535, 0.405], [-0.05, 0.285]], [[-0.39, 0.375], [-0.275, 0.26]],
 [[-0.2445, 0.1275], [-0.229, -0.147]], [[-0.117, -0.043], [-0.151, -0.046]], [[0.03, 0.0245], [0.047, 0.049]]]
```

We can try here: https://trinket.io/python3/b87762f44f

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I edited your source code and solved it using recursion:

```
def merge(arr):
  res = []
  for x in arr:
    if isinstance(x[0], list):
      res = res + merge(x)
    else:
      res.append(x)
  return res

regular_list = []
regular_list.append([[[-0.1905   , -0.4675   ],[-0.573    , -0.8115   ]], [[-0.468    , -0.3585   ],[-0.8145   , -0.7735   ]], [[-0.356    , -0.1435   ],[-0.7645   , -0.5415   ]]])
regular_list.append([[[-0.145     , 0.52      ],[-0.065     , 0.195     ]], [[-0.535     , 0.405     ],[-0.05      , 0.285     ]], [[-0.39      , 0.375     ],[-0.275     , 0.26      ]]])
regular_list.append([[[-0.2445    , 0.1275    ],[-0.229    , -0.147    ]], [[-0.117    , -0.043    ],[-0.151    , -0.046    ]], [[0.03      , 0.0245    ],[0.047    , 0.049    ]]])


print('Original list', regular_list)
print('Transformed list', merge(regular_list))
```

Maybe it's different from your expectations, but I think it meets the requirements:

```
[[-0.1905, -0.4675], [-0.573, -0.8115], [-0.468, -0.3585], [-0.8145, -0.7735], [-0.356, -0.1435], [-0.7645, -0.5415], [-0.145, 0.52], [-0.065, 0.195], [-0.535, 0.405], [-0.05, 0.285], [-0.39, 0.375], [-0.275, 0.26], [-0.2445, 0.1275], [-0.229, -0.147], [-0.117, -0.043], [-0.151, -0.046], [0.03, 0.0245], [0.047, 0.049]]
```

Make sure the smallest unit is an array with only 2 elements. Or you can improve it according to your purpose.

Comment: Thanks. It works very well with more than 2 dimensions. However, it doesn't work with 1 dimension. Can you check my example here? [https://trinket.io/python3/c583fd713c](https://trinket.io/python3/c583fd713c)

Comment: As I noted, the unit is a 2-element array. What is the expected result for this example?

Comment: It must be `['s0022lre', 's0022lre', 's0022lre', 's0022lre', 's0022lre', 's0022lre', 's0022lre', 's0022lre', 's0022lre', '100', '100', '100', '100', '100', '100', '100', '100', '100']`

Comment: try change ```if isinstance(x[0], list)``` to ```if isinstance(x, list)```

Comment: It works, but the result of the 1st issue is impacted. The length of the array is double.

Comment: Are you asking for 2 outputs for the same problem?

Comment: I created another new function to solve the problem. Then, it is solved. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
def flat_func(regular_list):
    res = []
    for idx,item in enumerate(regular_list):
        print(idx, item)
        if idx==0:
            res.append(item)
        else:
            for i in item:
                res.append(i)
    return res
regular_list = []
regular_list.append([[[-0.1905   , -0.4675   ],[-0.573    , -0.8115   ]], [[-0.468    , -0.3585   ],[-0.8145   , -0.7735   ]], [[-0.356    , -0.1435   ],[-0.7645   , -0.5415   ]]])
regular_list.append([[[-0.145     , 0.52      ],[-0.065     , 0.195     ]], [[-0.535     , 0.405     ],[-0.05      , 0.285     ]], [[-0.39      , 0.375     ],[-0.275     , 0.26      ]]])
regular_list.append([[[-0.2445    , 0.1275    ],[-0.229    , -0.147    ]], [[-0.117    , -0.043    ],[-0.151    , -0.046    ]], [[0.03      , 0.0245    ],[0.047    , 0.049    ]]])
  
expectation_list = [[[[-0.1905, -0.4675], [-0.573, -0.8115]], [[-0.468, -0.3585], [-0.8145, -0.7735]], [[-0.356, -0.1435], [-0.7645, -0.5415]]],
 [[-0.145, 0.52], [-0.065, 0.195]], [[-0.535, 0.405], [-0.05, 0.285]], [[-0.39, 0.375], [-0.275, 0.26]],
 [[-0.2445, 0.1275], [-0.229, -0.147]], [[-0.117, -0.043], [-0.151, -0.046]], [[0.03, 0.0245], [0.047, 0.049]]]

print('Original list', regular_list)
print(expectation_list==flat_func(regular_list)) 
#True
```

Comment: It works well with 2 dimensions, but not with more than 2 dimensions (I tried with 3 dimensions --> not work).